# Entity Framework - Refresh Binding Source

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting started with Entity Framework and have got reading/writing working. I'm stuck on refreshing the data on the binding source when I've added data.

e.g. User opens a new form as dialog and enters a new records into the database. When it returns to the new form, how do I go about refreshing my data?

I'm using this to bind the data on form load:

```
employeeBindingSource.DataSource = context.Employees.ToList();
```

I've tried a few thins online like below (both true and false) without any luck

```
 employeeBindingSource.ResetBindings(false );
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?
I'm using C#, Latest Entity Framework, Bound to a DevExpress GridControl (V17.1)

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q403949/how-to-refresh-the-grid-view-after-updating-the-datasource

Comment: Not sure what EF are you using (EF6, EF Core), but in both cases you should bind to `DbSet<T>.Local` property. Something like `context.Employees.Load();` and then `employeeBindingSource.DataSource = context.Employees.Local;` (or `.Local.ToBindingList();` in case of WinForms)

Comment: Thanks, KalpeshRajai, this didn't work for me.
@IvanStoev - I don't have the .Load() for my context. could there be another command? I'm using EF6

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure how I missed this as I was sure I tested it. In my situation using this below worked and my grid was refreshing.

```
employeeBindingSource.DataSource = context.Employees.ToList();
```

If anyone has a better answer please let me know.

Comment: Same situation, bindingSource refreshed after running program and defining data source with database table.